# Comparing 3 column lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, matrix, dataframe

I am looking for a loop in R which can compare a three column matrix. What I'd like the loop to do is take two matrices/dataframes of the format

---

```
 A:
 X    Y    Z
 3    4    5
 3    5    6
 4    5    7
```

and

---

```
B:
X    Y    Z
3    4    5
3    4    4
3    4    7
4    5    7
```

and loop through each of these returning the row if all of the 3 columns are exact matches.

This would return

---

```
X    Y    Z
3    4    5
4    5    7
```

Ideally the code could be applied to longer matrices/data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `intersect` from `dplyr` if "A", "B" are "data.frames"

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(A,B)
```

Or

```
inner_join(A,B)
```

Answer (score 3):

An option in base R is `merge`:

```
merge(A,B, by = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
#  X Y Z
#1 3 4 5
#2 4 5 7
```

This approach works the same way with matrices and data.frames.

And in fact, you could even leave out the specification of the "by" argument in this case:

```
merge(A,B)
#  X Y Z
#1 3 4 5
#2 4 5 7
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data are big you can use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table); setDT(A); setDT(B)

setkey(B)[A,nomatch=0]
#   X Y Z
#1: 3 4 5
#2: 4 5 7
```

`setkey(A)[B,nomatch=0]` returns the same output since it is an intersection.